# How to add new rows at bottom of tableview - chat messages

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using the following code to add new messages every time the user types a message and click 'send'. It works great. But the problem is, new messages are inserted at the top of the table view. I want it to be inserted at the bottom.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var messagesTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var messageTextBox: UITextField!

    var messageArray = [String]()

    @IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

        messageArray.append(messageTextBox.text!)
        messagesTable.reloadData()
        messageTextBox.text = ""

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messageArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        //self.messagesTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(messagesTable.frame.height,0,0,0)

        let cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AgentMessageText", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AgentMessageText
        cell.messageText.text = messageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

The below code insert rows to bottom. But the newly inserted rows are below the view point. That is we have to scroll to see it every time

```
self.messagesTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(messagesTable.frame.height,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Seeing at your code your messages are inserted at the bottom not at the top. The problem you're facing is that you have to scroll to see them, right?

Comment: Add message to your messageArray and insert your row with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, then use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to scroll to that newly added message

Comment: Also as to why the messages are being added to top, you have to show us how do you update your datasource array for new message. As Inder Kumar Rathore said, Your cells shouldn't be added at bottom looking at your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. There's no need to reload whole TableView either, you can just use scrollToRowAtIndexPath and scroll to last element

Comment: @InderKumarRathore exactly

Comment: @NSNoob can you show me the full code? I didn't get it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A common solution to this problem is to flip the tableview (so cells stick to the bottom) then flip the cells so the content is oriented properly.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //flips the tableview (and all cells) upside down
    messagesTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
}
```

...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   ...

   //flips the cell to appear oriented correctly
   cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
```

**For Swift 4**

Just to be clear, for Swift 4.0 the above transform function is as per below

```
CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

Comment: Yes. It would be a great help if you can show me the code

Comment: when I am using same method for UICollectionView, CollectionView is fliping but cells are not. any solution?

Comment: I'm annoyed by how well this actually worked, handles scrolling well too

Comment: I implemented this. It works fine. But my collectionview keeps scrolling infinitely at the top. Is this solution only for table views?

Answer (score 1):

You've to use `scrollToRow` to scroll to your message (use .bottom/.top/etc. acc. to your need)
Also instead of reloading your whole table view you can add just one (new) message(cell) to table view

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
  messageArray.append(messageTextBox.text!)
  messagesTable.reloadData()
  let indexPath = IndexPath(item: messageArray.count, section: 0)
  messagesTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
  messageTextBox.text = ""
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: "use of unresolved indentifier 'indexPath'

Comment: are you using swift 3?

Comment: Then check how to create indexpath in swift2

Comment: if I use this func to receive messages while scrolling my tableView jumps around, any possible solutions ??

Comment: Inder, you say you are just reloading one cell but you have line messagesTable.reloadData() in your code which reloads whole table

Comment: @user1904273 I don’t know why I wrote it. I’m on mobile right now I’ll update my answer and remove the reload statement and insert the cell insertion code. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

For Scroll To Bottom In Your Chat App

```
For Swift 3.0
```

Write a function :

```
func scrollToBottom(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.dataArray.count-1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

and call it after you reload the tableview data

```
tableView.reloadData()
scrollToBottom()
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5. Write a function:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()  let index = 
self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows  self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: (index?.last)!, at: .top, animated: true)
```