# tableview can't show messages from bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cgaffinetransform

I am creating Chat App With Swift and firebase every thing works perfect for me but I want like whats app when new message received or sent that it appears on bottom of `UITableView`. For that I have tried using below code but it won't work for me

**Code**

in side `viewDidLoad()` I have written below code

```
chatTableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(Double.pi));
```

and in side `cellForRowAt indexPath` I have written below code

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi));
```

but this code is not working for me always new message appear on top not on bottom of tableview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add new rows at bottom of tableview - chat messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157645/how-to-add-new-rows-at-bottom-of-tableview-chat-messages)

Comment: @Astoria i tried solution from that link but not worked for me i am stucked here why its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)` instead of rotation in both cases.

Comment: inside `viewDidLoad()` or inside tableview method?

Comment: @VishalParmar as I said - both

Comment: i tried but still new message going top of tableview not bottom

Comment: Thanks you are right this work for me just issue is that i am appending messages into array instead of inserting