# UITableView: how to scroll from bottom (like a conversation list)?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to create a list using a `UITableView`, making the rows appear from the bottom, just like a conversation list (Messenger for example).

I tried a basic example playing with the header height (which would take the remaining height of the table view based on its content size). Here is what I wrote:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var headerHeight: CGFloat {
        tableView.bounds.size.height - tableView.contentSize.height
    }
    // MARK: Instance Properties
    var heights: [CGFloat] = []
    
    // MARK: Table Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBAction func add() {
        heights.append(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200)))
        tableView.reloadData()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.heights.count - 1, section: 0),
                                       at: .bottom,
                                       animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Init
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: .main)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    // MARK: Life
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: ViewControllerCell.reuseIdentifier, bundle: .main),
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: ViewControllerCell.reuseIdentifier)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero,
                                     size: CGSize(width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: headerHeight)))
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        headerHeight
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let v = UIView(frame: .zero)
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        return v
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        .leastNormalMagnitude
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        heights.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ViewControllerCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerCell
        cell.constraint.constant = heights[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class ViewControllerCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "ViewControllerCell"
    // constraint sets a random height for the cell
    @IBOutlet weak var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

I set the header view background red to see it precisely in this example. But for some reason, this only works one time in two :

[image]

Could you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy and common solution is to flip the `UITableView` (around the Y axis). Where you setup your UITableView or in `viewDidLoad` do:

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

And in your `cellForRowAt` or inside the custom cell setup:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I found the same solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157645/how-to-add-new-rows-at-bottom-of-tableview-chat-messages, it works perfect.
However, I also had to reverse the cells order in order to always display the latest message at the bottom:
`let reversedIndex = (0..<heights.count).reversed()[indexPath.row]
cell.constraint.constant = heights[reversedIndex]
return cell`